# Laravel Guzzle Zillow API call returns "You don't have permission to access on this server" live server but works fine locally

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I wrote a little application that connects to the Zillow api using Guzzle in laravel 5.4.

It all works great until I deploy it to a live server at which point I get

> You don't have permission to access /webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm on this server.

returned from the gizzle catch.

If I change the url from zillow to www.google.com it gizzle returns the response.

If I copy paste the zillow url into a browser it gives me the correct xml response.

This is a new live deployment with the virtual host directory pointing at the sites "public/index.php/"

What could possibily becausing this. I'm a bit stumped at this point. All the other instances of this bug seem to be caused by virtualhost or apache config files pointing to the wrong directory.

So my question is, if I'm hosting a domain on ubuntu at

> var/www/domain.com/public_html/laravel/

and pointing to "var/www/domain.com/public_html/laravel/public/index.php" in virtualhost.conf file for this domain, where else must I point to this location to make this work? This is the only domain on this server.

Any clues pointing me in the right direction would be tremendiously appreciated.

*EDIT*
Here's the address that's used to make the call.

```
$addressf = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=X1-APIKEY&address=".$addressf;
```

$addressf contains a valid http parsed address used for testing. This address works fine in a browser but not the call except on the local machine.

Here's the actual catch where the error is returned

```
try {
    $response = $client->get($addressf);
      //$response = $client->post($this->url, $params);
  } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {

    var_dump($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());

  }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you show your code that makes the request? Can you dump out the url that you are attempting to access?

Comment: Done, Hope that helps

Comment: It's possible that zillow has blocked the ip address of your server. Can you try ssh'ing into your server and using `wget` to access the url?

Comment: You're correct. I get the same forbidden response when I wget from the ssh terminal on the server! I had written that posibility off already. I guess now I just need to find out why/how to unblock it. Thank you patricus!

Comment: Sure thing. I posted a quick answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you're getting would be from Zillow, so it's not related to how your server is setup.

My guess would be that Zillow has blocked your live server, so that you're getting a straight 403 response, and not even an API response with an error code.

If you're using a shared host, you may have an issue getting the IP address unblocked, since it is most likely block from inappropriate access by one of your neighbors. If it's a dedicated host, you may have better luck, but will need to make sure you operate within their terms of use so you're not blocked again. Either way, you will need to be in contact with Zillow to resolve this.